# Localization in Telerik Reports(TRDX reports)

Tags: asp.net, telerik-reporting, report-designer

We are working on a reporting requirement where fixed format reports created in Telerik standalone report designer(.TRDX report files) will be hosted in an asp.net web application. Whenever end users wish to change the layout of TRDX reports they can edit(add or remove a column) the reports using standalone report designer and copy the report back to solution path, now the new layout of report would be displayed when the dot net application page is refreshed in a browser. We are able to achieve the above feature.

Now we are trying to add localization to TRDX reports, but not much documentation is given on that. When an end user wishes to change the language of report header, the report headers ,labels must be displayed in the selected language. The data values would be displayed as is from database.

Thanks,
Daniel

Comment: did you find any solution ? i have same issue but telerik documentation not shows any related example

Answer (score 0):

No out of the box option is available to serialize XML reports (trdx) still you can utilize User Functions to get the localized labels string [documentation](http://www.telerik.com/help/reporting/advanced-localizing-reports.html)