# Report localization in Telerik self hosted service (.trdx)

Tags: asp.net, localization, telerik-reporting

I have telerik REST web API(ASP.NET ) which is working fine. Now I need to localize the reports (report are in .trdx extension).

From documentation of telerik I found the code which have place in my `BaseTelerikReportsController` but this also not working, and even not show any error.

[Telerik Localization Documentation](https://docs.telerik.com/reporting/advanced-localizing-reports)

```
public class BaseTelerikReportsController : ReportsControllerBase
    {
        static readonly Telerik.Reporting.Services.ReportServiceConfiguration ConfigurationInstance;

        static BaseTelerikReportsController()
        {
            var resolver = new CustomReportResolver();

            //Create new CultureInfo
            var cultureInfo = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("aa-iq"); //<-- Line 1

            // Set the language for static text (i.e. column headings, titles)
            System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = cultureInfo; //<-- Line 2



            var reportsPath = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/Reports");

            ConfigurationInstance = new Telerik.Reporting.Services.ReportServiceConfiguration
            {
                HostAppId = "TBReportApp",
                ReportResolver = resolver,
                // ReportResolver = new ReportFileResolver(reportsPath),
                Storage = new Telerik.Reporting.Cache.File.FileStorage(),

            };


        }


        public BaseTelerikReportsController()
        {
            ReportServiceConfiguration = ConfigurationInstance;
        }


    }
```

**Note**
There is a similar question but don't guide me to any right direction [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33239793/4154016)

**Update 1**

I have added below function in `Global.asax.cs`.

```
 protected void Application_AcquireRequestState(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           //Create new CultureInfo
           var cultureInfo = new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("ar");

           // Set the language for static text (i.e. column headings, titles)
           System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = cultureInfo;

           // Set the language for dynamic text (i.e. date, time, money)
           System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = cultureInfo;


        }
```

After above line (see image) data under red mark is localize but i need to localize yellow one(i.e heading)

[image: Update 1]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figure out how to localize the report header. Following are the some summarized steps.

1. Add `App_GlobalResources` folder and `.resx` accordingly your languages (See the figure 1-1).
   [image: Figure 1-1]
2. Send language attribute from 'HTML5 Viewer'.

   ```
         var viewer = $("#report-viewer").data("telerik_ReportViewer");

     var model = {
         //other attributes
         Language: this.selectedLanguage //Here value may be ,en Or ar
     };


     viewer.reportSource({
         report: reportSettings,
         parameters: model
     });
   ```
3. On server side based on that attribute change label accordingly.

   ```
          private static void Localization(ref Report reportInstance)
       {

           ResourceManager currentResource = null;
           switch (_language)
           {
               case "en":
                   currentResource = new ResourceManager("Resources.en", System.Reflection.Assembly.Load("App_GlobalResources"));
                   break;

               case "ar":
                   currentResource = new ResourceManager("Resources.ar", System.Reflection.Assembly.Load("App_GlobalResources"));
                   break;

           }
      //    var MyResourceClass = new ResourceManager("Resources.ar", System.Reflection.Assembly.Load("App_GlobalResources"));

           ResourceSet resourceSet = currentResource.GetResourceSet(CultureInfo.CurrentUICulture, true, true);

           foreach (DictionaryEntry entry in resourceSet)
           {
               string key = entry.Key.ToString();
               string value = entry.Value.ToString();

               var items = reportInstance.Items.Find(key,true);

               foreach (var singleItem in items)
               {
                   var singleItemType = singleItem.GetType();
                   //if (singleItem.GetType().FullName == "") ;

                   if (singleItemType.FullName == "Telerik.Reporting.TextBox")
                   {
                       var castItem = (Telerik.Reporting.TextBox) singleItem;
                       castItem.Value = value;
                   }
               }



           }


       }
   ```

**On Telerik Standalone Report Designer**

Change your report(.trdx) `Textbox` value which matches your `.resx`name value pair.

[image]

**Resource file values**

[image]